# Query only return ids where does't have a relationship with where

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Doing a query on some data but I can't workout how to do this efficiently-- querying users and joining with a table of dates-

I want the users who have do NOT have a record in the second table with a matching date but they have multiple records so if I just did  `select * from users join dates on users.user_id=dates.user_id where dates.date != '8/3/2020';`, shevy and rob would still be returned because row 4 still matches for shevy.

```
users       dates
-------         -------
id name         id  user_id date
1  shevy        1   2       8/1/2020
2  rob          2   1       8/3/2020
                3   2       8/10/2020
                4   1       8/17/2020
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: what excatly are matching days, no one of the match

Comment: On the where add “AND users.id=user_id” and let me know what happen.

Comment: Also, try using Left Join Instead of join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would use NOT EXISTS...

```
SELECT U.ID
      ,U.NAME
  FROM USERS U
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM DATES D
          WHERE D.USER_ID = U.ID
            AND D.DATE = '8/3/2020'
       )
;
```

As an aside, this seems like a basic ANSI SQL question and is not really a Snowflake question.

Comment: I specified Snowflake because Snowflake has additional funcs that can be applied if needed (re: resources).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want:

```
select u.*
from users u left join
     dates d
     on u.user_id = d.user_id and d.date = '8/3/2020'  -- should be 2020-08-03
where d.date is null;
```

This gets you users that do not have the specified date.

Comment: This approach works, but you would need to change "u.user_id" to "u.id" to match the schema provided by the OP.

Comment: @DarrenGardner . . . Interesting point.  The OP's query has:  users.user_id=dates.user_id.